# Tetrapaks vs. canned food

Tags: packaging

How does one know if slightly crushed tetrapaks are safe to eat from? I have never heard of problems from them but wonder as they get a bit crushed from picking them up repeatedly. This article [How to Know if Canned Food is Safe Past its Best Before Date](http://www.gettystewart.com/safety-of-food-in-cans-cartons-after-the-best-before-date/) says to avoid package if it is cracked, crimped or pinched but perhaps that applies to cans? Thanks!

Comment: Why should food go bad if the container has dents? As long as it's not ripped there should be nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the damage to its layers.

This is the layout of a tetrapak container:
[image: Tetrapak layout]

Now, obviously the container should not be considered safe if layers 1-3 are compromised. But small damage in layers 4-6 should not be considered invalidating.

Since the package is flexible, I don't think that slight crushing compromises any of the more important layers.

Comment: Thank you, I feel better knowing that there are six layers, I thought that there were only three!